# Testing Rails App with Testacular and AngularJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to setup testacular with angular e2e to test my rails application.
I can't get the most basic test to pass. My Rails app is running.

testacular.config.js

```
basePath = '.';
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  '*_spec.js'
];
exclude        = [];
reporters      = ['progress'];
port           = 8080;
runnerPort     = 9100;
colors         = true;
logLevel       = LOG_INFO;
autoWatch      = true;
browsers       = ['Chrome'];
captureTimeout = 5000;
singleRun      = false;
proxies        = { '/': 'http://localhost:3000/' };
```

test_spec.js

```
describe('Home Page', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('/');
  });
  it('should have h2', function() {
    expect(element('body').html()).toContain('Explore')
  });
});
```

Output: I'm selecting the body so you can see that its not my webpage but the testacular iframe. I would think I would see the body of my real page here.

```
expected "Explore" but was "\n  <h1 id=\"title\" class=\"offline\">Testacular - starting</h1>\n  <ul id=\"browsers\"></ul>\n\n  <iframe id=\"context\" src=\"about:blank\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>\n\n  <script src=\"socket.io/socket.io.js\"></script>\n  <script src=\"testacular.js\"></script>\n\n\n"
```

Comment: I had some trouble with testacular and rails and ended up using the jasmine gem instead with no issues.  Obviously not an answer to your question, but you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In testacular.config.js files array,

```
JASMINE,
JASMINE_ADAPTER,
```

and

```
ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
```

should not be used together.
The first set is for Jasmine specs,
the second set is for e2e testing.
They are mutually exclusive.

In your case, you are doing e2e testing, so the files array should be:

```
files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  '*_spec.js'
];
```

See also:
https://github.com/testacular/testacular/issues/66